# a few signposts

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

[image]

Assign an integer (1 through 16) to each cell so that:

- 16 is in the cell with the star; and
- each integer's arrow points to its successor (i.e. the next integer), though not necessarily in the adjacent cell.

Assume all arrows are vertical, horizontal, or at a 45° angle.

---

(This is what Simon Tatham's puzzle collection calls a "Signpost" puzzle.  His puzzles, though, always tell you where 1 is, and frequently where other numbers are, too.  I decided to try making a puzzle that tells you where only the *last* cell is.  I'm afraid I've therefore made it too easy; please let me know.)

---

Edited to add: [This can also be solved on Mr. Tatham's site.](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/puzzles/js/signpost.html#4x4:eccg16aadgcgfabccg)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that

> there are many cells whose successor is locked to one cell. Let's mark them with variables.
> `a1` is a shorthand for `a+1`.
>
> [image]

Now look at

> the cell marked as `b1`. Its successor cannot be `a1` because that would mean `b1=a`.
> Therefore its successor is `a`. Similarly, the successor of `f1` is `e`, and that of `c1` is the cell right above it.
>
> [image]

Then,

> the successors of `b3` and `f3` are also fixed, since e.g. `b1` and `b2` are smaller than `b3` and therefore
> cannot be its successor.
>
> [image]

> The successor of `d1` cannot be `d` or `c1`, so its successor is `f`. Then `d6` (previously `f4`)
> connects to `c` by the same logic.
>
> [image]

> Since the only candidate for the successor of `b4` is `16`, `d` becomes 1 and `d9` connects to `b`.
> This finishes the puzzle.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 10):

Here is the solution:

> [image]

Edit:

Here is the improved solution path

> The top row because of the ‘b tile’ needs obviously a concatenation of integers like so:
>  [image]

> There are only two options for 15 and with one of the options, any way you try to achieve the concatenation will make you have to use the x tile as ‘an exit’. But then we run into a dead end:
>  [image]

> So the other option has to be 15 and this leads us to
>  [image]

> As you can see a and b needs to be concatenated like so therefore the ‘b’ tile cannot be 8 which then forces:
>  [image]
>  [image]

Previous path

A solution path:

> I thought regressing from the star is the best way to start. What I then saw was that there were two possibilities for 15.
>  I tried one of them but it led me to dead ends with every conceivable variation:

For example here is a couple of such cases:

> [image]
>  [image]

> So I tried the only other option that could be 15, 14 being in the square below was then forced and with the first variation I tried with the possibilities for 13 being the ‘variations’, the solution was very straightforward to see using basic deduction! My stategy was if this did lead to a dead end hypothetically, I would have just tried the other options for 13 and other variations based on them until the solution is found (which aren’t too many).
>  [image]

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in three main steps.

First:

> All arrows one cell away from the edge that they are pointing towards must lead to that one cell.
>  [image: Step 1, link arrows pointing to a single edge cell.]

Next:

> Some arrows point to a line of cells, but all but one of these cells has already been claimed. These arrows must point to the remaining cell.
>  [image: Step 2, link arrows with only one possible destination.]

Lastly:

> A cell chain cannot link to itself, because that would create a loop. So the last cell in each chain must lead to the first cell of another chain.
>  [image: Step 3, link arrows from the end of one chain to the start of another chain.]